# How to troubleshoot Serilog?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

I have started to use Serilog in all kind of projects and there is almost always some problems with log data that is not coming through.

For example, right now I have a simple C# .NET core 6 project. All needed nuggets is installed and the project starts as it should but no file with log data is created. I turn on selflog to track the problem :

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
```

But there is no more info printed to the debug windows?

Here is some parts of the winform application :

```
    [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
                // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
                ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
    
                Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
                var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())   
                                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                                .Build();
    
                var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration();
                Log.Logger = loggerConfig.ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();
    
                var appSettings = AppSettingsHelper.GetAppSettings();
                var mainPresenter = CompositionRoot(appSettings);
                Application.Run(mainPresenter.GetViewForm());
            }

static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(AppSettings appSettings)
        {
            var httpClient = CreateHttpClient();
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .UseSerilog((hostingContext, configuration) => configuration
                                                                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                                                                        .Enrich.FromLogContext())
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddTransient<IMainModel, MainModel>();
                });

        }
        static IMainPresenter CompositionRoot(AppSettings appSettings)
        {
            var hostBuilder = CreateHostBuilder(appSettings);
            var host = hostBuilder.Build();

            var serviceProvider = host.Services;
            
            return serviceProvider.GetService<IMainPresenter>();
        }
```

I can see in debug mode that it have loaded the appsettings and the file sink :

```
{
  "serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Enrichers.Environment"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "/Logs/log.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} {SourceContext} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 1000000,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": "true",
          "shared": "true",
          "flushToDiskInterval": 3
        }

      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To get log data some of theses are executed but still no file :

```
_logger.LogInformation("...");
```

So how do one troubleshoot this problem? Where can find out why the file is not created?

**Edit:** By adding write to console in appsettings and switching my winform project to a console project I can see that I get log data as expected. But there is stil no file created?

**Final Edit :** Okay, so after a couple of hours I found a suggestion on stackoverflow, the "Serilog.Sinks.File" should be included in the using like this :

```
  "serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Enrichers.Environment","Serilog.Sinks.File"
    ],
```

The question of this topic do however remain, how do one troubleshoot this without spending hours, selflog is clearly not enough.

Comment: Maybe you are looking in the wrong location for the file. Have you tried using an absolute path, just to make sure this is not the issue?

Comment: @MortenChristiansen, found the solution, see final edit, but the question of the topic still remains, how do you really troubleshot Serilog efficiently?

Comment: Quick question, how far did you get into this wiki doc? Have you tried the PDB symbols for debugging through Serilog's symbols? https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics

Comment: @2189490 the problem is that I get no response at all from serilog, not even an exception. I find it strange that a tool that is made for logging seems to not be very good at log itself. Missing a using should give a exception when importing the appsettings serilog config.